# In ReactJS why does componentDidMount keep getting called for me when trying to wrap jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I followed [this guide about using DOM libraries like jquery UI alongside reactJS](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md).  I ended up with the following code to test what happens when I change a prop of my dialog, in this case it is the title.

```
var Dialog = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div();
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.node = this.getDOMNode();
    this.dialog = $(this.node).dialog({
      title: this.props.title
    }).data('ui-dialog');

    this.renderDialogContent(this.props);
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
    this.renderDialogContent(newProps);
  },

  renderDialogContent: function(props) {
    React.render(React.DOM.div({}, props.children), this.node);

    if (props.open)
      this.dialog.open();
    else
      this.dialog.close();
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.dialog.destroy();
  },
});

var MyApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <Dialog title={"Dialog - " + (new Date().getTime()) - this.props.start} open={true}>
        <h2>This is my dialog content!!!</h2>
    </Dialog>
  }
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    setInterval(function() {
      React.render(
      <MyApp startTime={start}/>,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
    }, 1000);
});
```

The dialog pops up, but every time the interval ticks, another dialog is created.  The dialog's componentDidMount function is called every second.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't call `React.render` inside of a component. Every time the interval ticks, you are unmounting and remounting your dialog, triggering `componentDidMount`. Every time this happens it initializes and opens the dialog, causing the behavior you're seeing.

I would move the `startTime` prop to `MyApp`'s state, then set up the interval function in `MyApp`'s `componentDidMount` event. The interval function should call `setState` instead of `React.render`. This will cause the new time to flow down to your `Dialog` component, which can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` event to update the dialog's `title` option without reinitializing the jQuery.

I would also suggest removing your `open` prop on your `Dialog` component and letting React handle the unmount process. You can decide whether or not to render the `Dialog` component in `MyApp` based on state.

Something like this:

```
var Dialog = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>;
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var dialog = $(this.getDOMNode()).dialog({
      title: this.props.title
    }).data('ui-dialog');
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function (newProps) {
    $(this.getDOMNode()).dialog('option', 'title', newProps.title);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    $(this.getDOMNode()).dialog('destroy');
  }
});


var dialogInterval;

var MyApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      openDialog: false,
      time: new Date().getTime()
    };
  },

  handleDialogToggleClick: function () {
    this.setState({openDialog: !this.state.openDialog});
  },

  render: function() {
    var dialog;

    if (this.state.openDialog) {
      dialog = <Dialog title={"Dialog - " + this.state.time}>
        <h2>This is my dialog content!!!</h2>
      </Dialog>;
    }

    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleDialogToggleClick}>
        Toggle the dialog
      </button>
      {dialog}
    </div>;
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    dialogInterval = setInterval(function() {
      this.setState({time: new Date().getTime()});
    }, 1000);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    dialogInterval = null;
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  React.render(
    <MyApp />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should give you an idea of what I'm talking about.